# Post request not working with Rest-Client but It's OK with Faraday and Postman

Tags: ruby, api, rest-client, faraday

I have a POST request to login a testing site
This request works fine with cURL or Faraday gem, but not working well with rest-client gem.

1) With cURL

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://mysite.vn/api/tokens?email=my_email@gmail.com&password=my_password12&grant_type=password' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 5dea5d74-80e6-41b1-87bc-ee3c81cf754a' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

#

2) With faraday

```
request_body = '{"email": "my_email@gmail.com", "password": "my_password12", "grant_type":"password"}'
conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'https://mysite.vn/api/tokens')
response_faraday = conn.post do |req|
      req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
      req.body = request_body
end
puts response_faraday.status
```

#

3) With rest-client

```
new_payload = {
        email: 'my_email@gmail.com',
        password: 'my_password12',
        grant_type: 'password'
    }
    response_resclient = RestClient::Request.execute(
               method: :post,
               url: 'https://mysite.vn/api/tokens',
               payload: new_payload.to_json,
               headers:  {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'})
```

puts response_resclient.code

For 1 and 2, both are correct. They all returns status 201, login successfully, but It failed with 3 - Rest_Client. The status is 404

I tried to use httplog to inspect and here is the log file

Faraday:
D, [2019-01-18T00:25:10.228043 #7764] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Connecting: mysite.vn:443

```
D, [2019-01-18T00:25:11.355649 #7764] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Sending: POST http://mysite.vn:443/api/v2/tokens/
D, [2019-01-18T00:25:11.356434 #7764] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Data: {"email": "my_email@gmail.com", "password": "my_password12", "grant_type":"password"}
D, [2019-01-18T00:25:11.362419 #7764] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Status: 201
D, [2019-01-18T00:25:11.362419 #7764] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Benchmark: 0.053334 seconds
D, [2019-01-18T00:25:11.363419 #7764] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Response:
201
```

Rest_Client:

```
D, [2019-01-18T00:37:29.982352 #12472] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Connecting: mysite.vn:443
D, [2019-01-18T00:37:31.105052 #12472] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Sending: POST http://mysite.vn:443/api/v2/tokens/
D, [2019-01-18T00:37:31.105052 #12472] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Data:
D, [2019-01-18T00:37:31.111003 #12472] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Status: 404
D, [2019-01-18T00:37:31.112000 #12472] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Benchmark: 0.010938 seconds
D, [2019-01-18T00:37:31.112997 #12472] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Response:
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

With Rest-client gem, It returns 404 error after sent post request to mysite.vn with code 443. I have no ideal with this case. 
Would you please help me to explain this case. and How do I correct this with Rest-Client

Comment: Hope you have a `require 'json'` in there?

Comment: Yes, I have required 'json', but It did not wor out T_T

Answer (score 0):

From the Rest_Client debug, you might aware that the `Data` is empty.

```
D, [2019-01-18T00:37:31.105052 #12472] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Data:
```

It seems you treat it wrong. Try this instead:

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://mysite.vn/api/tokens' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 5dea5d74-80e6-41b1-87bc-ee3c81cf754a' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{"email": "my_email@gmail.com", "password": "my_password12", "grant_type":"password"}'
```

See `man curl` for more information about `-d` flag.

Comment: Hello, my API can be requested by two ways
+ With parameters in the URL. That why you cannot see data in the CURL
+ With parametesr in the body, the CURL will be like you said before:

curl -X POST \
  
  https://mysite.vn/v2/tokens \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: ee0fcbeb-3772-45bf-bdef-190201da825a' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
     "email": "my_account@gmail.com",
 
     "password": "my_password12",
 
     "grant_type": "password"
}'